# PlayFramework 2.6.x - Execute Application Startup Code

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

This question is with regard to play! java 2.6.x

I am attempting to bootstrap some initialization code which needs to be executed during application startup

As per documentation, I have a class called Module in root package

```
  public class Module extends AbstractModule {

  private final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("application");

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    logger.info("Loading Modules");
    bind(ConsumerBootstrap.class).asEagerSingleton();
  }

}
```

However it is not behaving as expected. The binding only occurs when I trigger a request on a specific route, rather than eager binding on application startup.

I am running the application using `sbt run`

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Using `sbt testProd` did it . In dev mode eager loading is only triggered upon first request initiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said : This is by design. If you want to see it in action from sbt, run sbt testProd instead of sbt run.